# WhatsApp API - retrieving phone number ID and access token

Tags: facebook-graph-api, whatsapp

Phone number ID and/or access token from Quick start is invalid when used outside Quick start test message.

I've created WhatsApp app in Meta for developers, registered number, sent out test messages from Quick start page. When trying to use same phone number ID and access token from my local script I get this issue:

[image: I'm using GuzzleHttp client to make request]

Do I need to create permanent access token for this user? Where I can find phone number ID?

Answer (score 5):

For phone number ID, go to https://developers.facebook.com/apps and select the app where you have added WhatsApp. On the left side, click WhatsApp -> Quickstart. [image]

Select 'Start using the API'
On the next page you can find your Phone number ID:[image]